# Xpath, R: select nodes whose attribute values match a value in an array/vector

Tags: r, xpath

I have the following code

```
<paragraph id = "xx">
<text>hello</text>
</paragraph>

<paragraph id = "yy">
<text>bonjour</text>
</paragraph>

<paragraph id = "zz">
<text>guten Tag</text>
</paragraph>
```

I also have the following vector

```
id_vector <- c("xx","zz")
```

I want to get the text that are in the paragraph nodes whose attributes id is either "xx" or "zz", namely get a character vector that would be

```
c("hello","guten Tag")
```

What would be a fitting XPath to use with rvest?
So far, I have tried the following XPath, with no avail

```
"//paragraph[@id = id_vector]/text"
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this work?

"//paragraph[@id = 'xx' or @id = 'zz']/text"

Comment: This works just fine, thank you very much. But I would love to iterate the process, and to make it work for an array that contains more than 2 strings. Do you have any idea on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Are @id attributes predictable some how or follow a pattern?

Comment: If you don't mind pasting your xpath together (or the `glue`/`stringr::str_glue` functions should make it easier) you can create the inner section with something like `paste(paste("@id", id_vector, sep = "="), collapse = " or ")`

Comment: @LMC no, they are just random number IDs

Comment: @camille this looks like an interesting solution, I will try and implement it, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original suggestion was missing the fact that the IDs need to be wrapped in quotation marks in the xpath, so I went ahead and put the whole thing together. Note that I added a `<doc>` tag as a dummy because the xml sample needs a parent node. Paste your IDs together with the `@id=` piece, collapse into your xpath string, and extract text as you would normally.

```r
library(xml2)
doc <- read_xml('
<doc>
<paragraph id = "xx">
<text>hello</text>
</paragraph>

<paragraph id = "yy">
<text>bonjour</text>
</paragraph>

<paragraph id = "zz">
<text>guten Tag</text>
</paragraph>
</doc>
')

id_vector <- c("xx","zz")
tags <- paste(stringr::str_glue("@id='{id_vector}'"), collapse = " or ")
xpath <- sprintf("//paragraph[%s]", tags)
xpath
#> [1] "//paragraph[@id='xx' or @id='zz']"
xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, xpath))
#> [1] "hello"     "guten Tag"
```